# How to list all streams (also live streams) in Flash Media Server?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flexbuilder, flash-media-server

Is there some sort of "ls" or "dir" command I can issue from client side?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the Flash Media Server to get information about such kind of command or api.

But I have another idea, you can create the Remote Shared Object at server side to store information you can access the remote shared object from the client side to get information. for that you have to write small server side scripting in "Server Side ActionScript".

Another way you can also write the server side java / JavaScript code for FMS and they will return the list of Live or recorded stream.

But best way is RSO (Remote Shared Object).